# How do I get the Brother DCP-135C scanner to work?

Tags: 11.10, scanning, scanner

I have a Brother DCP-135C printer/scanner connected to my Ubuntu 11.10 amd64 machine. I have managed to get the printer working, but it doesn't recognise the scanner.

I have installed the drivers from the Brother website, brscan2, etc., but it still doesn't work. How can I get the scanner working?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Brother FAQ](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html#f00101) you may need to copy files from `/usr/lib64/` to `/usr/lib/`.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to copy files from `/usr/lib64/` to `/usr/lib/`. That's because you are using 64-bit system and the drivers are 32-bit (for exact instructions refer to the [Brother FAQ](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html#f00101)). This step is just for the 64-bit Ubuntu.

Then edit your `/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules` file. You need root access to do that:

`sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules`

Search for # libusb device nodes section and add by the end of it this line:

`ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01ce", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"`

You can find the idVendor and idProduct numbers by running lsusb command:

`Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f9:01ce Brother Industries, Ltd DCP-135C`

There is also other way mentioned in the [Brother FAQ](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1c.html) it involves modification of other file `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` and it's recommended for this versions of Ubuntu 9.10, 10.04, 10.10, 11.4, 11.10 (probably also 12.04). Both of these methods should work.

You should also add saned to the group which owns your scanner device:

```
sudo adduser saned lp
```

Your scanner is definitely in that group (I own one). If you wanted to use other scanner device then Ubuntu has documentation for it [ScanningHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo) (look at Permission issues section).

When you are done with all these steps you should restart the computer. The scanner should work in both Simple Scan and XSane programs.