# How can I get my Brother DCP-135C to scan properly?

Tags: 11.10, scanner, brother

I have just intalled from scratch my Ubuntu 11.10 64-bits on my desktop and everything is working just fine. I've also had no problem to get the printer function of my Brother DCP-135C working with no problem. I just can't get the scanner to work.

I've tried the unsware [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81035/how-do-i-get-the-scanner-on-a-brother-dcp-135c-working) but that did nothing. The tricky thing is, if I call the scannig program as administrator (sudo simple-scan) it works fine, but I can't get it to work as a normal user.

Comment: Add the output of `scanimage -L` to your question please, that will help us troubleshot further and get your better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to edit your `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` file. For scan acess by a normal user in 11.10 add the following lines:

```
# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

See also [Brother FAQ](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1c.html) for other distributions and Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to copy files from `/usr/lib64/` to `/usr/lib/`. That's because you are using 64-bit system and the drivers are 32-bit (for exact instructions refer to the [Brother FAQ](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html#f00101)). This step is just for the 64-bit Ubuntu.

Then edit your `/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules` file. You need root access to do that:

```
sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
```

Search for # libusb device nodes section and add by the end of it this line:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01ce", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

You can find the idVendor and idProduct numbers by running lsusb command:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f9:01ce Brother Industries, Ltd DCP-135C
```

There is also other way mentioned in the [Brother FAQ](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1c.html) it involves modification of other file `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` and it's recommended for this versions of Ubuntu 9.10, 10.04, 10.10, 11.4, 11.10 (probably also 12.04). Both of these methods should work.

You should also add saned to the group which owns your scanner device:

```
sudo adduser saned lp
```

Your scanner is definitely in that group (I own one). If you wanted to use other scanner device then Ubuntu has documentation for it [ScanningHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo) (look at Permission issues section).

When you are done with all these steps you should restart the computer. The scanner should work in both Simple Scan and XSane programs.