# How do I make the scanner function of my Brother DCP-315CN work?

Tags: 11.10, scanning, brother

I have a networked Brother DCP-315CN printer/scanner that I've been using with Ubuntu since version 7.10. Each new version has required its own tricks but so far, I've always been able to make the machine work - until now with v11.10.

Printing is no problem and has just become easier with the years, not even requiring drivers from the Brother web pages but the scanning function now leaves me without a clue as to what to do. I've downloaded and installed brscan2 (which hasn't been updated by Brother since 2009) and other related drives just as with earlier Ubuntu versions. I have also applied the tip about copying a number of files from /usr/lib64 to /usr/lib but to no use.

brsaneconfig 2 -q tells me that I've correctly configured and registered the scanner, and dpkg -l tells me that the drivers are installed but still, no scanner application detects it.

scanimage -L, scanimage -T, sane-find-scanner, and brsaneconfig2 -d all state that there is no scanner device connected, which I find very strange since the two computers in the house still running v11.04 sees the scanner, and I can anyway print on the device even from Oneiric.

Any piece of advice that can put me on a forward-moving track would be very much appreciated.

Update: I've been playing around with VirtualBox on two different computers, testing both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Ubuntu. So far, the conclusion is that this problem is specific to the 64-bit version of 11.10. 32-bit or earlier versions of Ubuntu work fine with the scanner. As to the reason for the problem, I'm no wiser, however.

Update: More playing with VirtualBox. scanning works with 64-bit Fedora 16 (recent kernel) and Debian 6 (old kernel), but so far not with Ubuntu-based Mint 12. So the problem seems to be kind of ubuntuish up to now. Going to try OPENSuse as well.

Comment: Did you also try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/85595/3940?

Comment: Perhaps it's useful to add the download link to the brscan2 package, for future reference: http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html#brscan2

Answer (score 4):

I think the following lines do the job for the brscan2 package - Ubuntu 12.04 amd64, Networking DCP-560CN:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2* /usr/lib

sudo cp /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2* /usr/lib 

sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother2* /usr/lib/sane
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my ancient Brother MFC-7820N. Also *san*ity check: make sure you have `sane` installed. You might not notice it until after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

It finally works!

I evidently made a mistake when first following the tip on the Brother web pages copying a number of library files from /usr/lib64 to /usr/lib. I discovered this by accident when playing with the Ubuntu 12.04 beta 1 in a VM. Since that version is an LTS, I now know that Ubuntu will support scanning with my DCP-315CN for longer than the hardware is likely to last... :-)